# Using Bootstrap, how can I create multiple fullscreen div's to stack on one another

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html

I'd like to create a page with multiple 100% divs, stacked on top of one another. Similar to the [Bootstrap Cover Template Example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/), but with additional div's underneath the first screen. I've tried looking around a lot but haven't been able to find a solution. I know it's out there, maybe I'm just searching for the wrong things.

Comment: You could do `<div class="row">...</div>` and then another `<div class="row">...</div>` underneath it

Comment: The question is vague, can you show us some example code you've tried already or explain in slightly more detail what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MikeKoch What would I set the heights of the rows to? 100% isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using div's with a 100% height won't solve your problem. Since you're already looking at the Bootstrap I assume that you're not afraid of using Javascript or Jquery. Therefor, you can use this little code to set the height of you div always 100% of your screen.

```
$("div_name").css("min-height", $(window).height() );
```

Using this little code, will set the height of your div that's wrapping your section. So, for every part of your website that needs the height of your window ( 100% ) you have to use a 'wrapper' div. So it would be something like this:

```
<div class="section">
    <h2>Section 1!</h2>
    <p>This is just an section with the same height as your browser.</p>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h2>Section 2!</h2>
    <p>This is just an section with the same height as your browser.</p>
</div>
```

If you want an example, you can take a look at my portfolio: http://portfolio.stikkie.net/

Comment: This makes sense. What am I doing wrong here though? http://jsfiddle.net/TTgvn/ Also, you're portfolio is exactly what I'm looking for, looks nice too!

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, apparently html doesn't like assigning 2 classes to one div. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The key is to remind the html and body that they can be 100% height. : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/TeqPJ/)

p.s. you don't need bootstrap

### HTML

```
<section class="cover-thing first">
    first
</section>

<section class="cover-thing second">
    second
</section>

<section class="cover-thing third">
    third
</section>
```

### CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.cover-thing {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;  
}

.first {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.second {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.third {
    background-color: #f06;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using sections with the below css, it covers the entire screen. This should help.

**CSS**

`.section{
height:100vh;
}`.

> 1vh = 1% of viewport height and 100vh = 100% of height.
>   Here is the 
>   [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rasr1/vdag2hm7/)

Comment: For modern browsers, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To manage multiple - full screen - stacked divs, you have to use javascript in addition of css, because css can't make a 100% height on elements based on your screen size.
for example, add :

```
$("body > div").style("height", $(document).height());
```

to set the height of your screen on each direct child div of your body tag.