# Make Div Element 100% Height of Browser Window Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap 3 to design a HTML page and right now I am facing a problem. I want my `div` tag container to take 100% height of the browser window but using CSS only (no javascript).

I went through lots of questions in stack overflow itself but couldn't find a solution that could help me. I don't want to use `vh`, as when you resize your window it wont work properly or wont show the container properly and I have 5 `div` tag containers and want every container to be the same size of the browser window.

p.s I don't think `html` or `css` is required as it can be answered without the code.

Comment: Really? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719452/how-to-make-a-div-always-full-screen) shows up as the first result if you look for "make a div take all of the screen" and it seems to work [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/w4xq54ht/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Comment: @Remysc i have div which contains 5 more divs and i want every of those div to fit the browser window and i also have a margin of 15 px both on bottom and top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ycvyp2zp/) what you want?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#thediv{
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:stretch;
  position:relative;
}
.interiordiv{
  background-color:blue;
  width:50px;
  margin:15px auto 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="thediv">
 <div class="interiordiv">A</div>
 <div class="interiordiv">V</div>
 <div class="interiordiv">C</div>
 <div class="interiordiv">D</div>
 <div class="interiordiv">E</div>
</div>
```

If not please try to make it clearer, if you don't want to post code that's ok but post a mockup image or something.

Comment: thanks buddy but , i want to place those divs vertically . i want to have 5 divs and each div should occupy a single browser window and when i scroll down i should see the second div taking the same 100% width with 100% height of the browser window with those margins. thanks :)

Comment: Oh I think I know what you want now, is it [this](https://jsfiddle.net/01t9ndra/) ?? each div being as big as the entire screen with margins on top and bottom? if so all credit is due [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441970/using-bootstrap-how-can-i-create-multiple-fullscreen-divs-to-stack-on-one-anot)

Comment: it doesnt fit the exact screen , it will have the margin but 100% height container will come after that taking exactly 100% height and margin size of the image will be shown down.

Comment: So 100% of the height taking into account margin, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/01t9ndra/1/) then? not an elegant solution imho but a working one.

Comment: It is not working with Internet Explorer 11. Any idea on how to overcome  that?

Answer (score 2):

All that is required is to set the 'min-height' CSS attribute of the Div you wish to re-size:

`<div style="min-height: 100%"></div>`

Ensure your html & body tags have a `height` of `100%` also.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.. as you said you are using bootstrap, you might override the row class and achieve this easily.

```
.row{
height:100%;
}

<div class="row bg-success"></div>
<div class="row bg-danger"></div>
<div class="row bg-warning"></div>
<div class="row bg-info"></div>
<div class="row bg-primary"></div>
```

Here are the screen sizes I tested it with.

[image]
[image]
THESE TWO WERE FULL SCREEN DESKTOPS

[image]
[image]
THESE WERE NON-FULL SCREEN BROWSER

[image]
[image]
THESE WERE IPHONE RESOLUTION IN PORTRAIT MODE

[image]
[image]
THESE WERE IPHONE RESOLUTION IN LANDSCAPE MODE

Comment: what if i have a margin of 15 px for both bottom and top? and it only works when the browser is maximized, i also wants it to work however the browser is i mean maximizing shouldnt be mandatory to show that it fits the screen. Thanks

Comment: I checked that out with different browser states and sizes. I even checked it out in mobile phone. It works perfect for me in all states.

Comment: it works when the browser is full screen , i want it to work even if the browser isnt full screen. it should show the container in the browser window even if its not full screen.